# Flutter PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)) Error

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to make a desktop program with Flutter. And I will do transactions with Firebase Storage. I installed Firebase but when running I get an error like this:

[image]

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))
```

I am getting this error in the file named `messages_pigeon.dart`.

And although it gives an error, the program opens. But this error bothers me so much, it pops up every time I reboot. How can I resolve this error? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

As much as I know Firebase only works on Android, iOS, Web, and macOS. Desktop -  windows, and linux is not supported yet.